# Stuck on Algebra for Summation Problem

Tags: summation

I want to find what the exact value of this sum is. What I was given is: $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2i-1} + \sqrt{2i+1}}$$

The only thing I can think of is turning the denominator into the form:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(2i-1)^{\frac{1}{2}} +(2i+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

I was wondering if I could get a hint on what to do next.

Comment: Are you looking for an exact value, or just upper/lower bounds?

Comment: Looking to evaluate this sum. I'll update the question.

Comment: I am looking for maybe an algebra trick to split this fraction up so I can use some summation identities to make this sum more simple. I don't know exactly how to split this denominator.

Comment: Just rationalize the denominator and then it’s straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2i-1} +\sqrt{2i+1}}&=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sqrt{2i+1}-\sqrt{2i-1} \right)\\
&=\frac12(\sqrt{2n+1}-1).\\
\end{align*}

Comment: You can get to the result because the sum telescopes.